# HP Insight Manager - delay alerts?

Tags: hp

We have HP System Insight Manager (SIM) set up to monitor our internal Proliant servers. When an alert is raised, an email is automatically sent to our administrators; however, it's become far too "noisy" - with servers rebooting regularly due to patches or maintenance, we end up getting dozens of emails each day. My fear is that natural complacency will creep in, and before long a "real" alert will be missed in amongst the noise of benign alerts.

What would be great is if there was some way to delay alerts, so that they were only raised if a certain condition persisted - say a server was offline for more than 10 minutes. I've seen passing references to the ability to do this in SIM, but I can't find a way to actually set this up - does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Hi, have a look at this guide at page 61, if you havent already: http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c03651392-3.pdf. It is supposed to generate Emails in critical states.

Comment: @Diamant: The problem is that a server being down (even for a reboot) is deemed a "critical" state - I only want to know about a server being down for more than 10 minutes.

Comment: Now, I would consider a server restart as an critical even. As far as I can see, there is no way to customize SIM in this regard. May be you will need to implement a seperate monitoring system, where you have the possiblity to fine tune or customize the notifications to fit your needs.